# Eclipse console and java stacktrace colors

Tags: java, eclipse

I know I can change the background, standard out and standard error colors in the eclipse preferences for the console. But the stacktrace from my java errors are displayed in red (the error color) and blue for the clickable links. Where do I change that blue color? It's almost invisible if I change the console background to black.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change the color for `hyperlink`.

> Windows -> Preferences -> General - > Colors and Fonts - > Basic - >
>   Hyperlink Text Color

Comment: It's `Windows -> Preferences -> General - > Appearance - > Colors and Fonts - > Basic - > Hyperlink Text Color` in Juno version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Window->preferences

Type in color in the search box at the top left. The first in the tree you get below that search box is the place you want to click. Change `Hyperlink text color` and possibly `Active hyperlink text color` (general->appearance->colors and fonts)

Answer (score 0):

*Please review the following image depict how can you change the colour of link and error in eclipse:*

[image: change the background, standard out and standard error colors in the eclipse console]